# Angular JS - Is it possible to create factory or service with $provider other than in config()

Tags: angularjs

I have couple of question

1. Angular JS - Is it possible to create factory or service with $provider other than in config()
2. Is it possible to create $Provider instance with injector
   i,e angular.injector(['ng']).get("$provider"); - When I tried it was throwing error

Thanks in advance

---

Updating the question for more clarity

Actually my question was- is it possible to create a factory/service by the injector $provider. I know the difference between factory , service and provider.And also I know we can create a factory inside config() like

```
app.config(function($provide){
        $provide.factory('newFac',function(){
            return {
                newT : 'This is from confing()'
            };
        });
    });
```

Just curious to know whether is it possible to create factory outside config() with $provide

Comment: I don't understand your question, do you want to create a service called `$provider` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Angular JS - Is it possible to create factory or service with $provider other than in config()

Not clear what you are asking, but let me explain a bit. Only providers can be injected into `config` phase, nothing else, but the difference between provider/service/factory is not so much big, so basically you could write any factory, and inject into config, but you must name it correctly, and provide a method called `$get` this way angular knows what object exposes your factory into config. Don't get wrong, only providers can be injected into config, but you could write your factory as it's a provider.

Here's example.

```
var app = angular.module('test', []);
//simple service
app.service('service1', function(){
    //some stuff
});
//simple provider
app.provider('service2', function(){
    //some stuff
    this.$get = function(){  //now this provider can be injected into config
        return this; //there are only 2 differences, `app.provider` and `this.$get` method
    }
});

app.config(function(service2Provider){ //notice `Provider` prefix
    //some stuff
});
```

> angular.injector(['ng']).get("$provider");

This will work on your module, for example, your provider is *TestProvider*, and the module that creates this provider is *TestModule*, then you must use

```
angular.injector(['TestModule']).get("TestProvider");
```

Also it works for services, constants, values, factories

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually my question was is it possible to create a factory/service by the injector $provider. I know the difference between factory , service and provider.And also I know we can create a factory inside config() like                       app.config(function($provide){ $provide.factory('newFac',function(){ return { newT : 'This is from confing()' }; }); });                                    Just curious to know whether is it possible to create factory outside config() with $provide

Comment: Well, i don't think so, even if it's was possible, it doesn't make sense though, where would you use this factory?

Comment: Useage of factory is only inside controller, my question is is it possible to create one as I have asked in updated question